# My fragment_profile.xml doesnt show. Whats wrong with my program?

Tags: java, android, layout, fragment

I created a new fragment which is ProfileFragment.java  and also created fragment_profile.xml.
The program does not give any error but my layout doesnt show. What is wrong?

My ProfileFragment.java :

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    //firebase auth
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser user;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    //layout views
    ImageView avatar;
    TextView nameTxt, emailTxt, phoneTxt;

    public ProfileFragment() {
        //boş public constructor gerekli
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        //init firebase
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");


        //init layout views
        avatar = view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        nameTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
        emailTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.emailTxt);
        phoneTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.phoneTxt);

        /* giriş yapan kullanıcıların bilgilerini email yada uid kullanarak çekmek zorundayız
        Kullanıcı detaylarını email adreslerini kullanarak çekicez
        orderbyChild query kullanarak giriş yapılan email ile email key ini eşleştirerek kullanıcı detaylarına ulaşılıyor
         */
        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user.getEmail());
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                //gerekli veriler gelene kadar kontrol et
                for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    //verileri almak için
                    String name = ""+ ds.child("name").getValue();
                    String email = ""+ ds.child("email").getValue();
                    String phone = ""+ ds.child("phone").getValue();
                    String image = ""+ ds.child("image").getValue();

                    //set data
                    nameTxt.setText(name);
                    emailTxt.setText(email);
                    phoneTxt.setText(phone);

                    try {
                        // resim alınırsa ayarla
                        Picasso.get().load(image).into(avatar);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        // resim alınırken herangi bir sıkıntı varsa varsayılan olarak ayarla
                        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.add_photo_foreground).into(avatar);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

and my fragment_profile.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F1EDED"
    tools:context=".ProfileFragment">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="#2ECC71">
            
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/avatar"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/add_photo_foreground"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:background="#6AE493"
                    android:padding="5dp">
                </ImageView>
                
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/emailTxt"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/phoneTxt"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"></TextView>

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

I want to create a user profile page using firebase realtime database. The user details come from using email for current signed user. But my profile layout file does not work. How can I fix this problem? Whats wrong in my code?

My DasboardAvtivity.java -> For fragment transaction.

```
package com.gamze.pawsbook;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //FirebaseAuth
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    //Actionbar
    ActionBar actionBar;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        //ActionBar ve başlığı
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Profile");

        //profileTxt = findViewById(R.id.profileTxt);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        //Bottom navigation
        BottomNavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(selectedListener);

        //Home Fragment'ı boş default fragment olarak ayarlanması
        actionBar.setTitle("Home"); //ActionBar başlığını değiştirme
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content, homeFragment, "");
        ft.commit();

    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener selectedListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    //itemlere tıklanma özelliği ekleme
                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.action_home:
                            //home fragment değişimi
                            actionBar.setTitle("Home"); //ActionBar başlığını değiştirme
                            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction ftHome = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ftHome.replace(R.id.content, homeFragment, "");
                            ftHome.commit();

                            return true;
                        case R.id.action_map:
                            //map fragment değişimi
                            actionBar.setTitle("Map"); //ActionBar başlığını değiştirme
                            MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction ftMap = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ftMap.replace(R.id.content, mapFragment, "");
                            ftMap.commit();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.action_users:
                            //users fragment değişimi
                            actionBar.setTitle("Users"); //ActionBar başlığını değiştirme
                            UsersFragment usersFragment = new UsersFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction ftUsers = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ftUsers.replace(R.id.content, usersFragment, "");
                            ftUsers.commit();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.action_profile:
                            //profile fragment değişimi
                            actionBar.setTitle("Profile"); //ActionBar başlığını değiştirme
                            ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction ftProfile = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ftProfile.replace(R.id.content, profileFragment, "");
                            ftProfile.commit();
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };

    private void checkUserStatus() {

        //mevcut kullanıcıyı al
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null){
            //kullanıcı giriş yapmışsa burada kal
            //giriş yapan kullanıcının email i
            //profileTxt.setText(user.getEmail());
        }
        else{
            //kullanıcı giriş yapmamışsa main activity'e git
            Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        //uygulamanın başlangıcını konrtol et
        checkUserStatus();
        super.onStart();
    }


    //options menu dahil etme
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //menuyu dahil etme
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    //menu itemlerine onClick özelliği aktifleştirme

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        //itemlerin id'lerini al
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_logout){
            //hesaptan çıkış yap
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            checkUserStatus();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_dashboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">

//FrameLayout fragmentlerin üstüste gelebilmesi için daha kullanışlıdır
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
    </FrameLayout>

    //BottomNavigationBar
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottombar_menu">
    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>





</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Well, is your layout blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is showing from `fragment_profile.xml`.

[image]

Your question doesn't give information whether you are getting an empty view like above or you are not getting any view. I will try to answer on two ansumption.

1. Empty View
2. No View at all

**Empty View**

If you are getting empty view then you must put some `Logs` statement in your database responce, check if that database is returning some value.

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    //Log Statment
    private static final String TAG = "ProfileFragment";
    
    ......

query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                //gerekli veriler gelene kadar kontrol et
                for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    //verileri almak için
                    String name = ""+ ds.child("name").getValue();
                    String email = ""+ ds.child("email").getValue();
                    String phone = ""+ ds.child("phone").getValue();
                    String image = ""+ ds.child("image").getValue();

                    //set data
                    nameTxt.setText(name);
                    emailTxt.setText(email);
                    phoneTxt.setText(phone);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: \nName: "+name+" email: "+ email);

                    try {
                        // resim alınırsa ayarla
                        Picasso.get().load(image).into(avatar);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        // resim alınırken herangi bir sıkıntı varsa varsayılan olarak ayarla
                        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.add_photo_foreground).into(avatar);
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Data is empty");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: "+error);
            }
 }
 }
.........
```

You can use [breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) as well to further investigation.

**No View at all**

If view is not changing on ProileFragment then you must check how you are starting ProfileFragment.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frgment_container, new ProfileFragment()).commit();
```

If you are using [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate) then make sure you are navigating to correct destination.

I will also suggest you to strcture the code in following format under Profile Fragment -

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    //firebase auth
    ............

    //layout views
    ..............

    public ProfileFragment() {
        //boş public constructor gerekli
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //init firebase
        .................

        //init layout views
        .......................

        /* giriş yapan kullanıcıların bilgilerini email yada uid kullanarak çekmek zorundayız
        Kullanıcı detaylarını email adreslerini kullanarak çekicez
        orderbyChild query kullanarak giriş yapılan email ile email key ini eşleştirerek kullanıcı detaylarına ulaşılıyor
         */
        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user.getEmail());
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                .................
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                ...............
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Edit (activity_dashboard.xml)**

Try following layout file for activity_dashboard.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottombar_menu"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using `?attr/actionBarSize`, which is the standard action bar size for android.
Happy Coding !

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I tryed your things. First, i added log statements and the programs gives  D:ProfileFragment: onDataChange: name: .. email: ... and D/ProfileFragment: onDataChange: Data is empty messages. So i think it works successfully. After that i edit my ProfileFragment page,  added onViewCreated method as you said. But still i dont see my interface. The profile_fragment.xml is open correctly. My action bar title is change when i click profile fragment item.Still something going wrong but what? Please help... @NikhilSharma

Comment: could you post code of your activity/fragment, from where you are coming to ProfileFragment ....

Comment: I added  my DashboardActivity in my question. I am using this codes for change fragments.. @NikhilSharma

Comment: have you provided `R.id.content` to your fragment or frame layout under R.layout.activity_dashboard ?  if not then use `android.R.id.content` to get root view.

Comment: Yes my frameLayout id is content under the avtivity_dashboard.xml

Comment: then you must post your activity_dashboard layout as well, because I don't think there is any issue as in provided code so far, I know I'm asking for too much code but I just want to help :D

Comment: It's okey, i did

Comment: I fixed the problem. I cant believe this happened i just make         android:layout_height="match_parent" :D I realized while looking to send you frame layout height is 0dp :D  so thanks for your helps.. @NikhilSharma

Comment: glad you find it yourself, I just completed editing my answer for the same while I got your notification ...  Lol